# How to open a new window (or in a tab), but not give it focus

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a function that I want to open up a URL in a new tab on a click event, but not give that tab focus. Is this possible with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can't steal focus from a newly opened window. It's a security feature preventing sites from "taking control" of your browser. That would be a browser configuration setting.

As far as "hiding" focus from a popup, you might be thinking of what's called "PopUnder". Basically you use `window.open()` and set the option `_blank` and the paramater `alwaysLowered`, but it will not work gracefully for an average website. It requires you to have a [signed script](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/signed-scripts.html) and take advantage of the Netscape Security PrivilegeManager, like this:

```
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalPreferencesRead UniversalBrowserAccess"); // etc...
```

Sorry bro :)

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to open a new window, then set focus back to the current window. However, user settings may make this impossible, or it might already be the default behaviour.

Pop–unders are used by some web sites probably to disassociate the web site from the window (i.e. so you don't know where it came frome). So they are assuming a certain naivety on behalf of the user. They are considered spam and treated with the same contempt.

If you outline what it is you are trying to achieve using a pop–under, you might get advice on better ways of doing it. Or not. :-)

Comment: Thanks. I actually have a popunder already working. Im trying to do 2 things at once really.

On a click event:

1) open a URL in popunder window (working)
2) open a URL in a new tab, but dont give the tab focus.

I actually got this setup to work in Chrome. But in Firefox, the new tab opens and it gets focus. In Safari a new window is created instead of a new tab.

Comment: Here's my code:

 var URL = 'www.google.com'
      resultsNewTab = window.open(URL,'_blank');
      resultsPopUnder = window.open(URL,'popupwindow',"toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,copyhistory=0,status=0,scrollbars=yes");
     resultsPopUnder.blur();
     window.focus();

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge it is impossible bro.Since the user's browser Settings will conflict with your logic